# Formato de excel desde datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel, excel, datatable

quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar para modificar el formato de un archivo de Excel, tengo esta tabla donde traigo esta información

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table stable1 table-sm table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="table-dark text-white">
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Agente</th>
                                <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Cobrado</th>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Destinatario</th>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> DNI Destinatario</th>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <th> Label</th>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <th><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Peso</th>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <th>Retirado</th>

                                <th nowrap>Total Liq.</th>
                                
                                <th>Efectivo</th>
                                <th>Cheque</th>
                                <th>Prepagado</th>
                                <th>Bolivariano</th>
                                <th>Guayaquil</th>
                                <th>Pichincha</th>
                                
                                <th>Total $</th>
                                <th> -- </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody  class="table-light">
                            
                            @foreach($liquidaciones as $liquidacion)
                            <tr>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->casillero. '000' . $liquidacion->id }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->nomAgente }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->nomCobra }} </td>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td>
                @foreach($liquidacion->factura as $facturaNombreD)
                                            <p>{{ $facturaNombreD->nombres_d }}</p></br>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach ($liquidacion->factura as $facturaDniD)
                                            <p>{{ ($facturaDniD->dni_d) ? $facturaDniD->dni_d . ',' : '' }}</p></br>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S' )
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach($liquidacion->factura as $facturaguia)
                                            <p>{{ $facturaguia->guia }}</p></br>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td>
                                        @foreach ($liquidacion->factura as $facturaPesoOrdenv)
                                            <p>{{ $facturaPesoOrdenv->peso }}</p></br>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->nombre_retiro }} </td>
                                <td> {{ number_format( $liquidacion->total, 2) }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->efectivo }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->cheque }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->prepagado }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->bbol }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->bgua }} </td>
                                <td> {{ $liquidacion->bpic }} </td>
                                <td> {{ number_format($liquidacion->valRubros, 2) }} </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-edit-admin" data-id="{{ $liquidacion->id }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> 
                                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="/admin/printLiquidacion?id={{ $liquidacion->id }}"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="/admin/detalle?token={{ $liquidacion->token }}#detalles" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                </td>
                                @php
                                    $total              += $liquidacion->total;
                                    $efectivo           += $liquidacion->efectivo;
                                    $cheque             += $liquidacion->cheque;
                                    $prepagado          += $liquidacion->prepagado;
                                    $bbol               += $liquidacion->bbol;
                                    $bgua               += $liquidacion->bgua;
                                    $bpic               += $liquidacion->bpic;
                                    $totalcancelado     += $liquidacion->valRubros;    
                                @endphp
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($vcosto as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Costo</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                        @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                    {{-- end --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo -= $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvcosto += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($vgasto as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Gasto</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                        @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                    {{-- end --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">-{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo -= $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvgasto += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($votros as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Otros ingresos</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                        @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                    {{-- end --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo += $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvotros += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            @foreach($vremes as $costo)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>V. Remesas</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    {{-- codigo cesar --}}
                                    @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                        @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S') 
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                        @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                        <td></td>
                                        @endif
                                    @endif
                                    {{-- end --}}
                                    <td>{{ $costo->descripcion }}</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">0</td>
                                    <td class="text-dark">-{{ $costo->valor }}</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                @php($efectivo -= $costo->valor)
                                @php($totalvremes += $costo->valor)
                            @endforeach
                            
                                    
                            {{-- @endif --}}
                            @php 
                                $totalcancelado += $totalvotros - $totalvcosto - $totalvgasto - $totalvremes
                            @endphp 
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -5 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif>
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td>V. Costo</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvcosto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvcosto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvcosto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -4 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                {{-- codigo cesar --}}
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td>V. Gasto</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvgasto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvgasto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvgasto, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -3 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td>V. Otros</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvotros, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvotros, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvotros, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -2 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td>V. Remesas</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvremes, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvremes, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalvremes, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 
                                <td> -1 </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td>{{ number_format($total, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($efectivo, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($cheque, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($prepagado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bbol, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bgua, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bpic, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalcancelado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr class="table-secondary text-dark"> 

                                <td> -- </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                @if($cajaFactura == 'S')
                                    @if($mostrarNombreDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarDniDestinatario == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarLabel == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($mostrarPeso == 'S')
                                    <td></td>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                {{-- end --}}
                                <td>{{ number_format($total, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($efectivo, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($cheque, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($prepagado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bbol, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bgua, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($bpic, 2) }}</td>
                                <td>{{ number_format($totalcancelado, 2) }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                    
                </div>
```

Para esta tabla utilizo datatable de esta manera:

```
<script>
        $('.table').DataTable({
        "order": [
                 [0, 'asc']
             ],
             buttons: [
                 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
             ],
             dom: 'Blfrtip', 
             bProcessing: true
         });
</script>
```

Y me trae la información de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la primera imagen, para la parte de Destinatario, DNI destinatario, etc, hay ocasiones en las que no tengo resultados mientras que en la segunda tengo varios resultados y así pueden ir variando, pero bueno lo que quiero al descargar el Excel es que me lo descargue de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y no de esta que es como me la descarga
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno esa es mi pregunta, como le podría dar ese formato a mi Excel, esto es mas que nada para que al momento de hacer cálculos de campos como el peso pueda hacerlo de manera mas rápida y efectiva, de antemano gracias por su ayuda.